Using OpenCore patcher to install later macOS on an unsupported Mac
I have a Mac Pro (Early 2008) running El Capitan and I thought I’d try the OpenCore Patcher to install Monterey. Installation of the patcher and making a USB installer went fine, but when I reboot and hold down the option key to select the boot drive nothing happens. The screen remains black and there is no hard drive activity. Any idea what’s wrong?
